# Devise Controller Test - ActionController::UrlGenerationError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using OmniAuth through Devise in my Rails app. I'm trying to test that my callback method is being called properly and functions correctly. I am currently receiving an error when running my spec.

The error:

```
Failure/Error: get user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
    No route matches {:action=>"/users/auth/facebook", :controller=>"users/omniauth_callbacks"} missing required keys: [:action]
```

My spec:

```
#spec/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller_spec.rb
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Users::OmniauthCallbacksController, :type => :controller do
  context 'get facebook' do
    before do
      request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user] # If using Devise
      request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook]
    end
    it 'should create user, redirect to homepage, and create session' do
      get user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)
      expect(response).to redirect_to(user_omniauth_callback_path)
    end
  end
end
```

Support file:

```
#spec/support/omniauth.rb
OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:facebook] = OmniAuth::AuthHash.new({
                                                              :provider => 'facebook',
                                                              :uid => '123545',
                                                              :email => 'fake@fake.com'
                                                          })
```

Controller:

```
#app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env['omniauth.auth'])

    if @user.persisted?
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication #this will throw if @user is not activated
      set_flash_message(:notice, :success, :kind => 'Facebook') if is_navigational_format? #todo what is this doing
    else
      session['devise.facebook_data'] = request.env['omniauth.auth']
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => 'users/omniauth_callbacks' }
```

I think the issue is in how it's getting routed. I think action should just be 'facebook' not '/users/auth/facebook', but I don't know the right way to resolve this.

Comment: Did you ever solve it? I'm facing the same issue and the spec is right and works in older projects. Maybe happens only with newest versions of devise

Comment: Sorry @Fabio, I never figured it out!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this looking for answers like I did.
I had this problem when adding a second Omniauth strategy. Turns out the problem was I'd forgotton to include the strategy in my model declaration

eg I was already authorising with google

```
# app/models/user.rb
devise :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google]
```

but then wanted to add a second provider (eg facebook). I forgot to add facebook to the list of omniauth providers and so was getting that error when my spec ran. I fixed it by changing to

```
# app/models/user.rb
devise :rememberable, :trackable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:google,:facebook]
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error `missing required keys: [:action]` as you. After I read RSpec document, I found that the argument of `get` should be something like `:index` (the action name). Because I defined:

```
# app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb

class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    # ...
  end
end
```

So I changed `get user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook)` to `get :facebook` and added some omniauth mocks. Now it pass!